# Animating a paint stroke

Tags: animation, texturing, materials

I'm looking to create a painted animation similar to ESPNs broadcast package for the 2016 Euros. I can map an image to a plane just fine and have that plane follow a curve, but I'm having a hard time unfurling or "pulling" the paint in a way that looks fluid. I've looked at the case study for that project and I think they used C4D. I wanted to see about an equivalent method for Blender.

[Germany v Italy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86qe7.jpg)

[Video](https://vimeo.com/171658720)

Alternatively, I've thought about using metaballs generated as a particle following a path but it doesn't clump and stretch the way paint would when dragged by a brush across a surface. Admittedly, I'm relatively new to Blender so I'm sure there are options I haven't considered.

Thanks in advance; any help is appreciated!

Comment: The paint is a 3d object that is 'revealed' due to the alpha value coinciding with the keyframed position of an Empty object. I don't see anything that really seems like real fluid here in the video, as the motion is fast.

Comment: I think a Lattice Modifier could do the job.